# Determining visible area/invisible area of a masked object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mask, visible, area

I have a movie clip named circle_mc(see the image on the link below) and a mask object(movie clip) which determines visible area of the circle. User can change the portion which is visible (extend the red area and make it red+blue, gray area is invisible). I need to find proportion of visible area to invisible area (red+blue/gray) so that I can calculate angle.

[image: http://i52.tinypic.com/33w01le.jpg]

Comment: Do you know the angle from the top of the red to the bottom of blue?

Comment: I am trying to calculate that angle :)

Comment: How does the user change the portion of visible to non-visible? Do you have a swf-demo?

Comment: Imagine there are lines which user can pull to extend the area (see the pic on the link below) Mask object can grow so the visible area. I dont have demo, this is imaginary. 

http://i52.tinypic.com/2hmgegg.jpg

Comment: I found this function on the web which calculates visible height and width but I dont know how to calculate visible circle area.
http://plasticsturgeon.com/2010/09/as3-get-visible-bounds-of-transparent-display-object/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mathopenref.com/segmentarea.html) is a working example of a formula.